# javascript runtime error unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Below is the Javascript function to validate empty textbox, but I'm getting the error message:

> "javascript runtime error unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null".

I have checked the existing answers for this issue, but I still not sure why the `Textbox_login.ClientID` value is not getting picked up.

Please advise, thanks.

```
<script type ="text/javascript">

    function textboxvalidate() {
        var login = document.getElementById('<%=Textbox_Login.ClientID%>').value;

        if (login == "") {
            alert("Please enter a login");
            return false;
        }

    }
</script>
```

Comment: have you tried UniqueID? `var login = document.getElementById("<%= Textbox_Login.UniqueID%>");`

Comment: This is not Javascript only. You are also using C# I think

Comment: can you post your asp.net code as well?

Comment: Thanks for looking into this @Pream, UniqueID didnt seem to work.

Comment: @Weedoze, I'm using VB.net in Code Behind and I've not written any validations there. Javascript validation for checkboxes is working fine, issue is only with the text box, thanks for your time

Comment: @user7417866, I'm using VB.net in Code Behind and I've not written any validations there. Javascript validation for checkboxes is working fine, issue is only with the text box, thanks for your time

Comment: @Frank When you debug the JS what ID value do you get?

Comment: if possible give ID to your control and use ID into Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Please add `Tags: Asp.net`

You need to set the ClientIDMode attribute on the control to:

```
ClientIDMode="Static"
```

This works with .Net 4.0 and upwards.

MSDN documentation states with regard to the ClientIdMode:

> **Static**     The ClientID value is set to the value of the ID property. If the control is a naming container, the control is used as
>   the top of the hierarchy of naming containers for any controls that it
>   contains.

Example:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Textbox_Login" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
```

Comment: obviously he is using .net from his syntax ;)

Comment: Yes, I saw. ::)

Comment: @vanloc ClientIDMode is set to Static, issue persists, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if the Textbox_Login runat property set to server or the Textbox_Login element is inside another element that is runat server, then you can't get the element using document.getElementById()

and also you don't need to use c# code here. just put your element id

ex: var login = document.getElementById("Textbox_Login").value;

make sure runat property of Textbox_Login is not set to server and Textbox_Login element not within other elements those are runat server.

Comment: removing "runat=server" gives the error "No 'runat=server' attribute present on the textbox tag." Also, Textbox_Login is with in <form id="form1" runat="server">....</form> and I think, it doesn't work if placed outside that, thanks